# Apigee Client Application Client Authentication

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas

I can't seem to get the client application authentication to function using curl. I am using the example provided here: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-users-and-application-clients

I get the following error:

```
"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid username or password"
```

Is there something I need to do in my configuration?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using the correct app level credentials?

Comment: I am passing in the correct key and secret. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah - but there are org level and app level credentials. They look the same, so just checking you're using the correct pair.

Comment: I am using the org level credentials. I don't see app level credentials anywhere...

Comment: Deceivingly they're in the "Getting Started" section on the right hand side.

Comment: Can you post your curl so we can diagnose?  obfuscate the org, key, and secret, of course.  There isn't anything to configure.

Comment: Thanks @remus, I was using the wrong credentials. Everything works as expected.

Comment: Good stuff! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right credentials:

Org-level credentials can be found on the **Org Overview** tab, app-level credentials are found on the **Getting Started** tab (on the right-hand side).